# How to make a QheaderView multilevel?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qt5, qheaderview

I am creating an application that saves the data of an object sending service.

I created that with `Qt`, a model of type `QStandardItemModel` that I want to display with `QtableView`.

But `QtableView` shows me the line level on the left. I want to delete it or hide it if possible.

I also have a problem with a header that I want to divide into two horizontally then divide the corresponding part of the bottom in two vertically. The reason for these division is that I have two headers with similar beginnings (date of correspondence and correspondence number)

Thank you for your reply because it is really important for me.

[image]

Comment: Here's how you can hide the line numbers: `myTableView->verticalHeader()->hide();` But the second part of your question is much harder. I think the only feasible way would be to subclass `QHeaderView` and implement rendering the upper parts of two adjacent columns' headers as they are one singe column header.

Comment: As for my first question your answer works perfectly but the second one is a bit fuzzy for me, I think I will understand better with a visual also I will post mine (if I find the way) because I think the layout that I ' I chose is logical in this order but I am open to all suggestions thank you.

Comment: @eyllanesc  How it must look like https://i.imgur.com/ITXNWNc.jpg

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This type of `QHeaderView` does not exist, but we can create it for it we must create a class that inherits from `QHeaderView` and rewrite mainly the method `paintSection` which is the method in charge of drawing the sections of the `QHeaderView`.

But to do the generic project for any type of visual design we have to keep the information of the position and size of each section, for this we will create a model, to understand why of the overwritten classes I recommend you read content of the following [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-simpletreemodel-example.html).

Explain the logic of each method is extensive so only place the [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46469720) of the project that implements the above and describe the task of each class:

- `TableHeaderItem`: It is responsible for saving the information of each item, mainly rowspan and columnspan in addition to the label.
- `GridTableHeaderModel`: Model class that provides access to each item so that we can edit and read each item
- `GridTableHeaderView`: This class is the custom `QHeaderView` where the main methods are overwritten to get the desired look.
- `GridTableView`(optional): is a TableView that has methods to work directly with GridTableHeaderView.

Output:

[image]

*Note:* to hide the vertical header it is only necessary to use the `hide()` method:

```
horizontalHeader()->hide();
```

Comment: Thank you very much eyllanesc I tried to compile your code source there were some errors I managed to fix some that was due to files not included and I am currently reading your source code to try to understand much more your approach thanks again

Comment: The result that you get with the screenshot is exactly what I want. the screenshot for error https://i.imgur.com/8DH1h1J.png

Comment: I cloned your Github directory then and tried again but the same problems persist it's probably a due to my version of Qt as you say.
A qmake--version from my terminal gives me as a result:
QMake version 2.01 A
Using Qt version 4.8.7 in/usr/lib/i386-linux-gn

Comment: The first error is:

G ++-C-pipe-O2-Wall-W-D_REENTRANT-DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS-DQT_NO_DEBUG-DQT_GUI_LIB-DQT_CORE_LIB-DQT_SHARED-I/usr/share/qt4/Mkspecs/Linux-G ++-I.-I/usr/include/qt4/qtcore.pyd-I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui-I/usr/include/qt4-I.-O main. Main .cpp
In file included from main .cpp: 1:0:
Gridtableheaderview. H:10:95: Error: ' Q_NULLPTR ' was not declared in this scope
:: Orientation guidance, int rows, int columns, QWidget * parent = Q_NULLPTR;
^~~~~~~~~
Makefile: 233: The recipe for the target "main. O" failed
Make: *** [Main. o] Error 1

Comment: I just replaced the Q_NULLPTR by 0 and it works now very well

Comment: @eyllanesc It looks like your github link is dead, do you have a copy of this code I could view? I'm trying to make a multilevel header in PyQt5 and your picture is exactly what I want.

Comment: @eyllanesc Great got it now, thanks. This will be very helpful

Comment: @eyllanesc you mark my quastion as duplicate, but im asqking how to do same thing in python not c++. Im do not understand c++ code. And many peoples who will need same soluthion will googling that question by request with word "python". Many of they do not understand c++ too. Please reopen my question. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089638/double-header-using-qtableview-in-pyqt5?noredirect=1#comment109816496_62089638)

Comment: Awesome work. Have you considered making a small library of this an create a repo? I would very much like to post some questions/improvements on this